# How can we check channel is subscribed or not in pubnub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pubnub

I have subscribed channel during object create and unsubscribing it after destroy.But in some events subscribed channels showing blank array.

So how can I check any channel whether it is blank or not? Any method in ruby to check it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by object create and destroy. See my answer below and let me know if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Presence

Please review the [Presence Tutorial for Ruby SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ruby/presence-sdk-v4). You would use [here_now API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ruby/api-reference-sdk-v4#here_now) to find out who is subscribed to the channel.

For your Ruby server, you could also use [Presence Web Hooks](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ruby/presence-sdk-v4#presence-webhooks-http-post-payloads) to stay updated when clients join or leave any channel.